# Pulling radio button values with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form on my webpage that looks like this:

```
<form id="numberForm">
<input type="radio" name="number" value="singular"> singular <br>
<input type="radio" name="number" value="plural"> plural <br>
</form>
```

How do I pull the value of the currently selected radio button (without a submit action) in Javascript?

What I'd like is something along the lines of the following:

```
var formInput = document.getElementById("numberForm");
var numberInputValue = formInput.SELECTEDBUTTON.value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (using `querySelector` in JS) :

```js
function getSel() {
var formInput = document.getElementById("numberForm");
var rb=formInput.querySelector('[type="radio"]:checked'); //get selected radio button
document.getElementById('spVl').innerHTML = 'Selected value = '+rb.value;
}
```

```html
<form id="numberForm">
<input type="radio" name="number" value="singular"> singular <br>
<input type="radio" name="number" value="plural"> plural <br>
<input type="button" value="Get selected radio button value" onclick="getSel();" /><br>
<span id="spVl"></span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var form = document.getElementById('numberForm');
var radios = form.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; ++i) {
  if(radios[i].checked) {
    console.log("Radio button '" + radios[i].value + "' is checked");
  }
}
```